# How to retreive custom property corresponding to another property in azure

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, azure-dashboard

I am trying to write a kusto query to retrieve a custom property as below.
[image]

I want to retrieve count of `pkgName` and corresponding `organization`. I could retrieve the count of pkgName and the code is attached below.

```
let mainTable = union customEvents
    | extend name =replace("\n", "", name)
    | where iif('*' in ("*"), 1 == 1, name in ("*"))
    | where true;
let queryTable = mainTable;
let cohortedTable = queryTable
    | extend dimension = customDimensions["pkgName"]
    | extend dimension = iif(isempty(dimension), "<undefined>", dimension)
    | summarize hll = hll(itemId) by tostring(dimension)
    | extend Events = dcount_hll(hll)
    | order by Events desc
    | serialize rank = row_number()
    | extend dimension = iff(rank > 10, 'Other', dimension)
    | summarize merged = hll_merge(hll) by tostring(dimension)
    | project ['pkgName'] = dimension, Counts = dcount_hll(merged);
cohortedTable
```

Please help me to get the `organization` along with each `pkgName` projected.

Comment: A simple query looks like that: `customEvents | summarize count(tostring(customDimensions.pkgName)) by aa=tostring(customDimensions.organization)`. You can try to modify it to meet your need.

Comment: The query given by @IvanYang is giving me the correct count. However I need to project corresponding organization name as well. Something like
`packageName/organization` and its count

Comment: do you mean project the `count of packageName`, and `packageName`, and `organization`?

Comment: yes exactly. I could only project the count and either the package name or organization, not the both. But I want to project all three together.

Comment: I think we can create another table which contains `packageName` and its related `organization`, then join this table with yours. Let me give it a try, and update this thread later.

Comment: Really grateful for your time and response @IvanYang. Please update as an answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this simple query:

```
customEvents
| summarize counts=count(tostring(customDimensions.pkgName)) by pkgName=tostring(customDimensions.pkgName),organization=tostring(customDimensions.organization)
```

Please feel free to modify it to meet your requirement.

If the above does not meet your requirement, please try to create another table which contains `pkgName` and `organization` relationship. Then use `join` operator to join these tables. For example:

```
    //create a table which contains the relationship
    let temptable = customEvents
    | summarize by pkgName=tostring(customDimensions.pkgName),organization=tostring(customDimensions.organization);
    
    //then use the join operator to join these tables on the keyword pkgName.
```